# Checking to see if Facebook Event Subscription in Javascript is working

Tags: javascript, facebook

The Ajax below is on a file with a Facebook Like button.  The Like button works correctly.  I am trying to use the Ajax below to execute some PHP on a file called fblike.php when the Facebook Like button is clicked.  It's not working.  Is there any way I can check to see if `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {});` is actually firing?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script >

FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
   $.ajax({
   url: "fblike.php", // the url of your php script
   context: document.body,
   success: function(){
      // if you want something to be executed when a result comes back
                      }
         });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use firebug or the inspection tool in chrome/safari, or even IE Developer toolbar. Navigate to the NET tab, and see if any requests are sent to 'fblike.php',  alernatively add console.log or alert() messages to both success, and error callbacks.